# How to make friendly routes in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to make friendly routes in angular.
For example, I would need something like this:

example.com/my-post-title

instead of:

example.com/post/23

Thanks!

Comment: The /post/23 is only telling the router go to x route with y child, so when you can specific get the post you want from the route variables. instead of a number you can just create a dictionary that match the title you want with the id of the DB which will result at the end the same.

Comment: Exactly, the `my-post-title` value will be caught by the routerParams and you will use it to get your Post. So you should end up with a route like  `{ path: '/:slug ... }`

Answer (score 1):

At first I wanna mention why changing the URL from `example.com/post/23` to `example.com/my-post-title` is a bad idea. The `23` of your URL is most likely a unique identifier for the post, that should be loaded. If we replace the URL like you want to, the identifier is gone and after a reload or accessing the URL directly with `example.com/my-post-title` wouldn't work, unless you dig through your posts and search for the specific title.

I would recommend to add the more human readable text after the identifier. That way the URL is readable for a human and your application. So the URL would look like `example.com/post/23/my-post-title`

### 1. Changing the route

At first we need to add a parameter to the route for the slug, so we can fetch the slug later when the corresponding component has loaded, to check if the slug is already appended or not. But you will need two routes, one where only the ID is entered, if the user visits the URL without the slug, and one that includes the slug-parameter.

So your route should look something like that:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
...
  {
    path: 'post/:id',
    component: PostComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'post/:id/:slug',
    component: PostComponent,
  },
]
```

### 2. Replace the URL in the Item-Component

When the Post-Component loads, we wanna check if the slug parameter was set and if not, add it to the URL with the `replaceUrl` option of the `Router.navigate()`. With the `replaceURL` we can manipulate the URL without reloading the page or adding any entries to the browser-history.

```js
  setSlug() {
    const postSlug = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.slug;
    if (!postSlug) {
      // Simple function that replaces spaces with dashes
      let slug = this.dasherize(this.post.title);
      // Here happenes the magic. We append the slug to the current URL
      this.router
        .navigate([slug], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, replaceUrl: true })
        .then();
    }
  }
```

And now your components should add the slug when it is visited by the URL `example.com/post/23` to `example.com/post/23/my-post-title`!

Here is a working StackBlitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yudqtn?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Hope I was of help,
Lord Tkay